# Dataframe reverse for drop(column = )

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to manipulate a dataframe using a cumsum function.

My data looks like this:
[image]

To perform my cumsum, I use

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_sheet, sheet_name='Sheet1').drop(columns=['Material']) # Dropping material column
```

I run the rest of my code, and get my expected outcome of a dataframe cumsum without the material listed:

```
df2 = df.as_matrix() #Specifying Array format
new = df2.cumsum(axis=1)
print(new)
```

However, at the end, I need to replace this material column. I'm unsure how to use the add function to get this back to the beginning of the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, then you can just set the `material` column to the index, then do your cumsum, and put it back in at the end:

```
df2 = df.set_index('Material').cumsum(1).reset_index()
```

An alternative would be to do your `cumsum` on all but the first column:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].cumsum(1)
```

Comment: Easy enough. Thanks!